# c programming: need fresh eyes to look at this [demo code != homework]

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

Essentially I want qPtr[0] to hold sPtr[0]

```
struct myQueue{  
    struct sample* node;  
    int front;  
    int size;  
    int numElements;  
};  

struct sample{  
    int field1[5];  
    char field2[10];  
}  

int main(){    
    struct myQueue* qPtr = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct myQueue);   
    struct sample* samplePtr = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct sample); //assume this array has                     been initialized    
    enqueue(qPtr, samplePtr[0]); //this does not work
}  

//returns 1 if enqueue was successful  
int enqueue(struct myQueue* qPtr, struct sample* sPtr){  

    qPtr->node[(qPtr->front + qPtr->numElements) % qPtr->size] = sPtr;  //code pertains to circular array implementation of queues  
    return 1;  
}
```

I've been at it for about 2 hours now and would appreciate some clarification on what I'm doing wrong conceptually. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`samplePtr[0]` gives the object itself, not a pointer to the object. Try sending `&samplePtr[0]` or `samplePtr` itself. `enque` function, second parameter expects a type of `struct sample*` and not `struct sample`.

Comment: @jeeper_creepers - With your comment "assume this array has been initialized", I assume the struct members of `myQueue` are also intialized valid values. Is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
enqueue(qPtr, &samplePtr[0]);
```

The second parameter to enqueue() takes a pointer to a struct sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 fundamental problems.

- you're passing a `struct sample` object to `enqueue()` instead of a pointer to a `struct sample`. this should be caught by the compiler.
- you're setting up an array of queue structures instead of having a single queue structure object that manages an array of pointers to the objects that are on the queue.  This is a design problem.

Your code should probably look more like:

```
struct myQueue{  
    struct sample* node;  
    int front;  
    int size;  
    int numElements;  
};  

struct sample{  
    int field1[5];  
    char field2[10];  
}  

struct myQueue q = {0};

int enqueue(struct myQueue* qPtr, struct sample* sPtr);

int main(){  
    // get memory to hold a collection of pointers to struct sample:
    q.node = calloc(10, sizeof(struct sample*));
    q.size = 10;

    // allocate a sample
    struct sample* samplePtr = malloc(sizeof(*samplePtr));

    // put the sample on the queue
    enqueue(qPtr, samplePtr);
}  



//returns 1 if enqueue was successful  
int enqueue(struct myQueue* qPtr, struct sample* sPtr){  

    qPtr->node[(qPtr->front + qPtr->numElements) % qPtr->size] = sPtr;  //code pertains to circular array implementation of queues  
    return 1;  
}
```